# Devise + OmniAuth + Google_Apps: How do I "override" the stock Google Apps Domain form?

Tags: devise, omniauth, google-apps

I have integrated Devise + OmniAuth with the omniauth-google-apps strategy in my app based on the [examples](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) provided by the Devise folks. It all works fine with the following user flow.

- Go to my standard sign in page
- Click Sign in with Google Apps
- Enter Google Apps domain in form at users/auth/google_apps (standard
  OmniAuth form)
- Sign in to Google Apps (initiates standard callback to
  omniauth_callbacks after authentication)
- User is now signed into my application - hurray!

However, I want to "override" the standard stopgap OmniAuth Google Apps Authentication form with my own form (this is the form through which the user submits his or her Google Apps domain).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, after working on this for awhile, I think I've bumped into a good solution. I didn't "override" the standard stopgap OmniAuth Google Apps Authentication form per se, but here is what I did.

I added a `google_apps` action to my existing `SessionsController`

```
# sessions_controller.rb
def google_apps
  @title = 'Sign In with Google Apps'

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

I added a custom view to ask the user for her Google Apps domain (notice that the form simply POST's the domain to the same place as the OmniAuth form

```
-# google_apps.html.haml
= form_tag user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_apps) do
  %p
    = url_field_tag 'domain', nil, placeholder: 'example.com'
  = link_to_submit_form 'Sign In'
```

By the way, if you have a better solution, please post your answer.